# QSortFilterProxyModel not showing 2nd column in QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt4, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have inherited a class from QSortFilterProxyModel to support filtering of a hierarchical tree in my code.

I have added code below of what I have done. After filtering is done, data in the 2nd column is NOT shown...

I am not able to understand why is that...

Can anyone help me on that?

Also, when filtering is completed, the tree is collapsed... I want to call expandAll on the tree when the filtering is completed. Is there some signal emitted or some function called where I know that the filtering is done?

**Class Declaration**

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MySortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const;
    bool ShowThis(const QModelIndex index) const;

private:
};
```

**USAGE:**

```
    _proxyModel = new MySortFilterProxyModel(this);

    _proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(-1);
    _proxyModel->setSourceModel(_directiveTreeModel);
```

**DEFINITION:**

```
bool MySortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,
        const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    return ShowThis(index);
}

bool MySortFilterProxyModel::ShowThis(const QModelIndex index) const
{
    bool retVal = false;
    //Gives you the info for number of childs with a parent
    if ( sourceModel()->rowCount(index) > 0 )
    {
        for( int nChild = 0; nChild < sourceModel()->rowCount(index); nChild++)
        {
            QModelIndex childIndex = sourceModel()->index(nChild,0,index);
            if ( ! childIndex.isValid() )
                break;
            retVal = ShowThis(childIndex);
            if (retVal)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QModelIndex useIndex0 = sourceModel()->index(index.row(), 0, index.parent());
        QString name = sourceModel()->data(useIndex0, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        QModelIndex useIndex1 = sourceModel()->index(index.row(), 1, index.parent());
        QString value = sourceModel()->data(useIndex1, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
        std::cout << "name : " << name.toStdString() << ", value : " << value.toStdString() << "\n";// , filterRegExp : " << filterRegExp() << "\n";
        if ( (name.contains(filterRegExp()) || value.contains(filterRegExp())) )
        {
            retVal = true;
        }
        else
            retVal = false;
    }`enter code here`
    return retVal;
}
```

**OUTPUT : (Data in the 2nd column is missing)**

[image]

Comment: I figure out that it is not coming because of : 
_dTreeView->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)..

However, I do not know the solution. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue...

I was using QStyledItemDelegate and I had derived a class from it and overridden the paint function.

In the pain function, I was referring to my original model .. But, in case of filtering, that model is NULL and I should have used the proxy model that I had created.